# Can not Connect to Node Client. Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am writing this line of code to connect to mongodb via mongoose.

```
var db=mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bookapi');
```

But this is showing this error in command prompt.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
```

Help Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have to Run mongod from cmd. That was creating the error.

Comment: Thanks this is the simple thing we forget! Thanks mate!!

Answer (score 0):

This error primarily means that the node server cannot connect to the mongodb instance.

Reasons:

- Is the mongod service running?
- If the mongo db is not on localhost, check internet connectivity, firewall permissions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try connecting to mongodb://localhost:27017/bookapi
2. Check if mongoose is installed and running. if you are using windows please refer this https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/ for adding mongodb as a service.